# Does Oracle Unified Directory have a unique identifier for users

Tags: active-directory, ldap

The Microsoft AD has the objectGUID. Does Oracle Unified Directory has a similar field?

What I've found so far is entryUUID - but unsure if this field always exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entryUUID` Operational Attribute is defined in [RFC 4530](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4530).

> The attribute holds a server-assigned Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) for the object.